# How to create and enable a user in ldap using java?

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, jndi

I am trying to create a user in ldap using java, however user is being created but it is disabled, how to enable it while creation of the user, posting code that i am using for creation. Is any parameter missing or setting wrong attributes or password setting is wrong? Help me out.

```
        Attribute userCn = new BasicAttribute("cn", commonName);
        Attribute samAccountName = new BasicAttribute("samAccountName",samaccountname);
        Attribute userPassword = new BasicAttribute("userPassword",Password);
        Attribute oc = new BasicAttribute("objectClass");
            oc.add("top");
            oc.add("person");
            oc.add("organizationalPerson");
            oc.add("user");
        Attributes entry = new BasicAttributes(true);
        entry.put(userCn);
        entry.put(samAccountName);
        entry.put(oc);
        entry.put(userPassword);
String entryDN = "CN=" + userID.trim() + ",OU=abc,OU=def,DC=ghi,DC=jkl";
dirContext.createSubcontext(entryDN, entry);
```

**UPDATE 1**

I am getting the following exception/error while updating or modifying user for setting the password of a user and enabling it and i am using **private connection between** ldap server and my enviroment so should i need to use **SSL/TLS** configurations.

**ErrorCode 53 and WILL_NOT_PERFORM**

Comment: which LDAP implementation are you using and what attribute in the schema determines whether an user is active?

Comment: for ldap implementation-"needs to create an active user" and i dont know the attribute responsible for making it active thats why posted the question

Comment: What I mean with implementation is what 'brand', Active Directory, OpenLdap or another.
What tells you that a user is disabled? Are you using a particular client?

Comment: I am using Active Directory and by opening microsoft's ldap browser and hitting on user properties i get to know that it is disabled and i am not using any particular client just using java JNDI

Comment: If you're using Active Directory and Java JNDI your question has nothing to do with [tag:openldap] whatsoever.

Comment: Yes you need to use TLS.

Comment: I also tried using tls still it is giving me the same error

Answer (score 2):

AFIK, this must be due to the fact that you are setting the "userPassword" attribute which is not present in Microsoft Active Directory (by default).

The unicodePwd is the password attribute in Microsoft Active Directory and it requires "special" encoding to be set from JNDI. We show an example in this [source code](https://bitbucket.org/jwilleke/examples/src/91c2df9b5481b30e5ca213a7baa0ce7e0a04752c/Examples-JNDI/src/com/willeke/samples/ldap/jndi/ADConnection.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default).

So user entries created within Microsoft Active Directory with no password are disabled by default.

Also, for Microsoft Active Directory you [MUST use SSL-TLS](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Setting%20and%20Changing%20Microsoft%20Active%20Directory%20Passwords) to change the unicodePwd.

You may, but not recommended, Try setting the attribute [userAccountControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc245673.aspx) = 544 on the created user entry with no unicodePwd. You may need to do this after creation.

Comment: i tried your code but it is giving me error code 53 and "WILL_NOT_PERFORM" EXCEPTION

Comment: it seems like even after creating a user with `unicodePwd` it still stays disabled

Comment: @rajatravigarg14 do you have proper permissions? Are you using TLS?

Comment: @PhilippGrigoryev Try changing the account in MMC with the same user as in code and then logging in? Did that work?

Comment: I actually figured, that it requires two steps: first create a user, then set password and userAccountControl. Thank you, guys

Comment: can you put code, how you accomplished this ? I have same problem, tried many options. my target ldap server is MS active directory